# How to insert an HTML Table Inside a Grid Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, gridcontrol

I need to insert an Html Table inside a Grid Control. please see the image attached it shows what i need. 
in a normal grid control column or in gridcell it shows as html format with all headers but i need to remove that one.

enter image description here[image: now like this is showing]

i need like this as below image
[image]

Comment: Why not use a web browser control in that cell?

Comment: What have you tried already? Also I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04599562-8f77-44a2-8b57-3f7f2481e1e6/how-to-display-html-in-wpf?forum=wpf) after a few seconds of googling. Next time try to adhere to the guidelines about creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)